# Using Javascript framework with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, backbone.js

I'm building a system with Laravel (PHP framework) following its best pratices, and with little Javascript until now.

Laravel does not provide a simple way to delete items (I have a lot of CRUD in this application) and I have to use AJAX to delete an item and refresh the table with the items. Besides this action I want to show an alert (like the Bootstrap alerts, on the top of the page) saying that everything run ok, or with the errors that occurred.

I was thinking about to use a JS Framework like Angular, Ember, Backbone, Knockout (and others), instead of use all of that `hide/show` of jQuery. But I don't want to use *all the functionality*, like routing, views, and that communication client-server done by a back-end API sending JSON responses, because I have all the application already written in PHP (Laravel views).

Is there a way to use a JS framework for the data binding that I'm looking for? For now, I'm thinking just on the **delete** operation, but I'll have more Javascript/AJAX actions for sure.

**EDIT**

The main point here is that I want to trigger some actions on the UI as changes are made on the model (and just that), without using all of that `hide/show`of jQuery. Angular, Backbone and all of these frameworks provide it, but their examples shows a back-end API, and I don't want to use it. Knockout JS, at a first glance, fits what I'm searching for.

Comment: Angular is the only js framework that I have used extensively.  Certainly there is nothing that forces you to use all it's features.  The core file does not even include a router.  I suspect the other frameworks will be just fine as well.  Fair warning.  If you get comfortable with angular then I suspect your Laravel views will start to look less appealing.

Comment: How about react.js. I used angular for a long time. It's great framework but sometime it come up with some extra features you don't even need. Backbone might work either.

Comment: @NaingLinAung I was thinking about React JS (it has a state control over the components) but for now I'm gonna look for the other frameworks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, check packages like [laroute](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute)

You can generate a route for any action javascript side like this:

```
/** 
 * laroute.action(action, [parameters = {}])
 *
 * action     : The action to route to.
 * parameters : Optional. key:value object literal of route parameters.
 */

laroute.action('HomeController@getIndex');
```

**EDIT: Example added**

I have "master" page template whit a complex design (simplified here)

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="items-table">
        @include('_items_list', compact(['items']) )
    </div>         
</div>
```

I have a list of items in a partial blade template (also simplified)

```
//_items_list.blade.php
<table class="table" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <tr>
            <td >
                {{ $item->id }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $item->name }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger items" data-item_id="{{ $item->id }}">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my routes I use a POST method, but better approach is to use a [resourceful controller](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) implementing REST methods, you can use only the methods you want.

```
//routes.php
Route::post("items/delete.", "ItemsController@delete");
```

In my controller I have a delete method (also simplified)

```
//app/controllers/ItemsController.php
class ItemsController extends BaseController {

    public function delete(){

        $item = Item::find(Input::get('item_id'));

        if($item) {
            $item->delete();

            //return the new items list                
            $items = Tramite::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
           return View::make('_items_list', compact($items));
        }
    }
}
```

In my js file I have a jquery event listener like this

```
//public/js/items.js 
$(function () {

    $('.items').click(function(ev){

        var item_id = $(this).data('item_id');

        //Here comes the laroute library!
        //@see http://api.jquery.com/load/
        $( "#items-table" ).load( laroute.action('ItemsController@delete', {'item_id': item_id}, function() {
                console.log('New table loaded!');
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: This is so useful!! Maybe I will use it!

But I'm looking for something that can reflects model changes (caused by back-end responses) and the UI (data-binding)

Comment: I see... as stated by @Cerad, seems to be angular the way... i recommend you see this laravel + angular [excelent tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application). Personally I use jquery with laroute for this tasks. with the `$.load` jquery method. If you want an example i can post it.

Comment: Could you please give an example about your use of jQuery with laroute? @OmeCoatl

Comment: I added an example. I know are better approaches for this, but this is ease enough and works for me in specific cases.